# PHP CMS: "Call Home" function of sorts on install

Tags: php, content-management-system, monitoring

I am developing a web application that will be downloaded free for trial with other licenses for production sites. I know that these sorts of things are frowned upon but I would like to include a line or two in the install file to save the current install URL back to my database so I can cross check that with paying users. I am not trying to validate licenses (yet) these URLs would not be used in any way except to monitor for piracy. If the user removes this code or doesn't have an internet connection (installing locally) then there would be no error. Also, for legal reasons I would make the user aware of this function in the EULA.

Most call home functions out there use `file_get_contents` but they are validating, I just want to store a URL. Is sending a request with the URL escaped in a GET variable a viable option? Security, speed and functionality on a wide variety or server setups is key.

Any alternate suggestions are also welcome... I am still trying to figure out the best way to license and "protect" this software.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fairly simple version of the system, but it should do the job for now. It works by providing the current server's URL as the key, however you could swap that for a unique ID for the license.

For the CMS/application:

```
<?php
define('SITE_INVALID', 'invalid');
define('AUTH_SITE',    'http://www.example.com/verify.php');

function verify_install($key){
    $result = file_get_contents(AUTH_SITE.'?key='.urlencode($key));

    if($result == SITE_INVALID){
        return false;
    }

    // Valid
    return true;
};
?>
```

Then somewhere in your page (early on):

```
<?php
$site_key = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];    // Use current site URL (eg: www.example.com)

if(!verify_install($site_key)){
    // Invalid
    echo 'Your account is disabled';
    exit();
}

// Continue as normal
?>
```

And on the license server:

```
<?php
define('SITE_VALID',    'valid');
define('SITE_INVALID',  'invalid');

function verify_remote_install(){
    if(!isset($_GET['key'])){
        // Nothing sent - assume fine
        return true;
    }

    $key = urldecode($_GET['key']);

    // (Check if key in database, etc)
    $result = key_is_valid($key);   // Replace with your own method

    if(!$result){
        // Invalid
        return false;
    }

    // Valid
    return true;
}
?>
```

Then to verify:

```
<?php
$result = verify_local_install();

if(!$result){
    echo SITE_INVALID;
} else {
    echo SITE_VALID;
}
?>
```

You'll need to replace the `key_is_valid()` function with your method of verifying the key, whether that be checking if it's in the database or otherwise.

Also you'll be better to assume it is valid if you're unsure (eg: if the connection to the verification server fails, or if the key is not sent), that way should something go wrong that is outside the user's control, you'll give them benefit of the doubt. You want to give the best experience to the legitimate users, and stop the pirates if possible, rather than inconveniencing your paying users.

As said before, anyone with a basic knowledge of PHP (or even just able to read) could easily find this and disable it if the code is not obfuscated in some way. An open-source application to do that for you can be found at http://code.google.com/p/phpobfuscator/. If you want to still allow developers to modify the application, you could consider just obfuscating the licensing code, putting in a separate file and giving it an fake, innocent name.

Comment: This is great, thank you! As the description says, I am not trying to test a license just trying to aggregate the URLs where the software is installed into my database. Upvoted since I will most likely implement this in some way... but my concern is that I don't want the installer to rely on my server for a response at all. I am also worried about people seeing this script and then using the submission URL to send a bunch of false URLs to the database. Any ideas?

Comment: @cbh - I think I understand what you mean, in that case, to just send the current URL, just do `file_get_contents(AUTH_SITE.'?url='.urlencode($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))` to send the URL to the remote server (at the end if you don't need a response to not hold the page up), then on the remote server just store `urldecode($_GET['url'])` in your database. If you do end up using the licensing setup above, just keep the key as the site URL, or send it also, and you can save it still. Using some kind of separate key instead of just the URL for verifying would stop bulk checking. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out how http://www.socialengine.net/ encrypts their source code and gets the decrypt key and authorization. They are pretty big and would have reliable methods. I tried to crack it a while back for fun, but failed.

Comment: Thanks @ohmusama, but I would rather not go down the road towards file encryption just yet. I would like developers to feel welcome to adjust things as they like (even in a trial version). This is mostly just for a rudimentary way to check for piracy (although I am aware this method could easily be found and deleted from the code).

Comment: file() also can read remote hosts, you could also use a DB connect to connect to a remote SQL host with a "read only" db username and validate that way. There are many options.

If you are reallly realllllllly interested in doing something unique, try opening a socket and use your own protocal. More difficult to reproduce... except for $validated = true bypass...

Comment: Wow, didn't even think about those options... all really cool. The remote DB option won't work for now since I have to add the IP addresses of anyone remotely connecting (too bad, I like that one). And the custom protocol might be a bit beyond me. As for file(), I wouldn't need to read anything from my host, just send the URL as a string to it to store.